# Torricelli's law during freely falling cup

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, free-fall, weight

How Torricelli's law can be applied to freely falling cup with a hole?

It has been observed that in the free fall of the cup there will be no water coming out of the hole. But why?

Torricelli's law states that $v = \sqrt{2gh} $, but none of the above quantity tends to zero during any instant of free fall.

Comment: You have created and accelerated frame of reference. It's essentially the main postulate in General Relativity that the effective `g` will be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the frame of the free falling cup the acceleration of free fall, $g$, is zero.

Imagine you were in a free falling lift and you released a pebble.
To an external observer standing on the Earth the pebble would fall/accelerate at the same rate as you.
So relative to you the pebble will be stationary ie you would measure the acceleration of free fall as zero.